# Estimators of population mean:first observation

Tags: probability, estimators

I'm wondering if I have a random sample $y_0,y_1,...y_n$ drawn from $N(\mu, \sigma^2) $, and use $y_0$ as an estimator for the population mean, what would be the expectation and the variance of such an estimator?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

it will have expectation $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$